# Can't load custom httphandler over multiple projects

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, httphandler, ihttphandler

in my solution i have a couple of projects.

At my Allgemein.dll (General.dll) i have a custom httphandler which looks for pdf's and does something with it.

At every project in my solution i include the Allgemein.dll.

Now if i'm logged out of my application and i call a pdf, my httphandler works great.
But if i'm now login to my application and call a pdf, i got the following error: **"The type "Allgemein.Handlers.FileProtectionHandler" in the assembly "Allgemein" could not be loaded."**

What i'm doing wrong?

My web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
      <add path="*.pdf" verb="*" validate="true" type="Allgemein.Handlers.FileProtectionHandler, Allgemein" />
</httpHandlers>

<handlers>
      <add name="PDF" path="*.pdf" verb="*" type="Allgemein.Handlers.FileProtectionHandler, Allgemein" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

My FileProtectionHandler.vb

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Security
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web.SessionState

Namespace Allgemein.Handlers
    Public Class FileProtectionHandler : Implements IHttpHandler

        Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
            Get
                Return False
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext)
            Select Case context.Request.HttpMethod
                Case "GET"

                    If Not context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
                        Return
                    End If

                    Dim requestedFile As String = context.Server.MapPath(context.Request.FilePath)

                    If context.User.IsInRole("User") Then
                        SendContentTypeAndFile(context, requestedFile)
                    Else
                        context.Response.Redirect("~/Portal/Fehler403.aspx")
                    End If

                    Exit Select
            End Select
        End Sub

        Private Sub IHttpHandler_ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Sub

        Private Function SendContentTypeAndFile(ByVal context As HttpContext, ByVal strFile As String) As HttpContext
            context.Response.ContentType = GetContentType(strFile)
            context.Response.TransmitFile(strFile)
            context.Response.[End]()
            Return context
        End Function

        Private Function GetContentType(ByVal filename As String) As String
            Dim res As String = Nothing
            Dim fileinfo As FileInfo = New FileInfo(filename)

            If fileinfo.Exists Then

                Select Case fileinfo.Extension.Remove(0, 1).ToLower()
                    Case "pdf"
                        res = "application/pdf"
                        Exit Select
                End Select

                Return res
            End If

            Return Nothing
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like the handler is in the very same solution. Try omitting the assembly name then, i.e instead of `Allgemein.Handlers.FileProtectionHandler, Allgemein` try `Allgemein.Handlers.FileProtectionHandler`. Leave a message if this helps.

Comment: Hello and thank's for your help. Unfortunately its not working. Now the error is just: The type "Allgemein.Handlers.FileProtectionHandler" could not be loaded.

Comment: Another possible reason is that you have a non-empty "Root namespace" set in the project properties. Suppose this root namespace is "Foo". The actual type name would be `Foo.Allgemein.Handlers.FileProtectionHandler` then. A typical solution to this default namespace issue in VB.NET is to set it to blank, this however could cause other issues in your project. Leave a message if this helps.

Comment: You mean like that: <add name="PDF" path="*.pdf" verb="*" type="[BLANK]Allgemein.Handlers.FileProtectionHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" /> I Tried it and unfortunately its not working :(

Comment: But please look at my new sreenshot. The originating namespace is MIR.Web.Allgemein Does that make any different? I tried also this MIR.Web.Allgemein.Handlers.FileProtectionHandler but its still not working

Comment: I assume the `MIR.Web.Allgewhatever` is the root namespace. In this case, your actual type name would be `MIR.Web.Allgemein.Allgemein.Handlers.FileProtectionHandler` which is the root namespace [dot] the actual namespace from code [dot] class name.

Comment: Please check out my newest screenshot. After I made your changes i'm getting that strange string. Can I assume the handler is "working" and I do have a new/different problem?

Comment: Yes, this is a separate issue.

Comment: Okay, i was able to fix my problem. You're the best! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is this something you'd like to accept as an answer? I could make an answer out of these comments so that possibly someone else benefits from reading this in future.

Comment: Yes, I like doing that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a joined effort with the OP it has been concluded that the `MIR.Web.Allgemein` is the root namespace.

In this case, the actual type name would be `MIR.Web.Allgemein.Allgemein.Handlers.FileProtectionHandler` which is the root namespace [dot] the actual namespace from code [dot] class name.